# Process unread-command-events and redisplay

Tags: keyboard-macros, keystrokes, events, event-sequence

```lisp
(defun pretend (keys)
  (dolist (e (reverse (listify-key-sequence (kbd keys))))
    (push e unread-command-events)
    ;; (mystery-function)
    (redisplay t)
    (sleep-for 0.1)))

(pretend "M-x my-function-")
```

This function is *intended* to take key events and 'pretend' they were entered by the user at a reasonable pace of 100ms/key. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like `unread-command-events` is being processed – probably because emacs is not idle during execution.  One way to get around this is to abuse `run-with-idle-timer`, but this seems like the wrong approach.

How can I process/flush `unread-command-events` before continuing execution?

(I suspect I won't need the call to `reverse` after this is fixed.)

Comment: Very related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2461/2264; adding for the 'linked' sidebar list.

Answer (score 0):

You could used `recursive-edit` to put yourself into a situation where your events will be consumed. To make control return to your code, you must also add `(kbd "C-M-c")` (a.k.a `exit-recursive-edit`) to `unread-command-events`.

One limitation is that you will have to push complete key sequences, so you can't return to your code between the `C-x` and `2` in the key sequence `C-x 2`.

One concrete example where this is used is in the [test code](https://github.com/Lindydancer/dynamic-spaces/blob/master/test/dynamic-spaces-test.el) for [dynamic-spaces](https://github.com/Lindydancer/dynamic-spaces) (a package that try to make text to the right of the edit location to say in place). (N.B., I was not aware of the function `listify-key-sequence` when I wrote it, so it could probably be simplified.)